# Is it possible to change the thickness of the slider in wxPython?

Tags: wxpython

I have a slider with 2 states that will be used as a switch in a GUI on a touchscreen. I want it to be thicker. The image below shows how it looks. It is a magnified version. In reality, it is ~ 50 pixels tall. I need ~200.

```
self.sld = wx.Slider(self.panel, value = 0, minValue = 0, maxValue = 1, size = (300,50),style = wx.SL_HORIZONTAL|wx.SL_LABELS|wx.SL_AUTOTICKS)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the documentation for wx.Slider ([documentation](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Slider.html) wx.Python 4.0.7) and there is nothing mentioned about the thickness of the slider.